# How do I get the value of a variable out of the initState() block in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have got the value stored in Documents directory in initState() using widget.storage.readCounter() function. I want to get the value and store in TextEditingController as an initial value. But I am not able to get the value out of the initState() block. How do I get the value out of the initState() block? Here is my full code:

```
   class _UserForm extends State<UserForm> {
  TextEditingController uid;
  static String userid;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.storage.readCounter().then((int value) {
      userid = value.toString();
      /*setState(() => {
            userid = value.toString(),
          });*/
    });
    uid = TextEditingController(text: userid);
  }

   final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  //TextEditingController uid = TextEditingController(text: userid);
  final TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController myController2 = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController myController3 = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController myController4 = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController myController5 = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController myController6 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    uid.dispose();
    myController.dispose();
    myController2.dispose();
    myController3.dispose();
    myController4.dispose();
    myController5.dispose();
    myController6.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<SubmitData> _futureSubmitData;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Text('uid:' + uid.text),
        );
      },
    );
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                /*Visibility(
                  visible: false,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: uid,
                  ),
                ),*/
                TextFormField(
                  controller: myController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  decoration:
                      InputDecoration(hintText: 'Sale amount as per party'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter amount.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: myController2,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Item quantity'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter quantity.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: myController3,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Rate'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter rate.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: myController4,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Broker name'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter broker name.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: myController5,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Party name'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter party name.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: myController6,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Amount receivable as per party'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter amount.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.purple[400],
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 110, top: 10, right: 110, bottom: 10),
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        setState(() {
                          showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                content: Text('uid:' + uid.text),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                          /*_futureSubmitData = userData(
                              uid.text,
                              myController.text,
                              myController2.text,
                              myController3.text,
                              myController4.text,
                              myController5.text,
                              myController6.text);*/
                        });
                        Scaffold.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text('Submit', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            (_futureSubmitData != null)
                ? FutureBuilder<SubmitData>(
                    future: _futureSubmitData,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        if (snapshot.data.type == '1') {
                          /*showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                content: Text('Data submitted successfully.'),
                              );
                            },
                          );*/
                          Scaffold.of(context)
                            ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
                            ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                content: Text('Data submitted successfully.',
                                    style:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.green[100]))));
                          return Text('');
                        } else {
                          Scaffold.of(context)
                            ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
                            ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                content: Text(
                                    'Data not submitted. You have already submitted for today.',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red[100]))));
                          return Text('');
                        }
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                      }
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    },
                  )
                : Text(''),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

But I got the value of userid in initState(). But when I printed the value in showDialog() in **Widget build(BuildContext context)** which is after the initState() block, it gives blank value. My problem is how to get the value of uid in the **Widget build(BuildContext context)** block?

Comment: I have to use the uid out of the initState() block in the **Widget build(BuildContext context)** block. It gives blank value out side of the **initState()** block. This is my problem.

Comment: But the initState() method is out of the **Widget build(BuildContext context)** block. You mean I move the initState() inside the **Widget build(BuildContext context)** block? I have to get the value of userid in a **Form** widget which is in the **Widget build(BuildContext context)** block and then get the value in form submit.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong (***edit:*** I am wrong.), but I believe your problem is that "technically" you aren't assigning the value of your variable *inside* the initState method, but in a callback.

What you could do is rewrite the callback as such:

```
     @override
     void initState() {
     super.initState();
      widget.storage.readCounter().then((int value) {
         setState( () => {
           userid = value.toString();
         });
       });
     }
```

Comment: Sorry! This did not help. I got the value of userid inside the initState() block but did not get the value outside the block. I have to get the value in **Widget build(BuildContext context)**  and use it in a **Form** widget and then get the value in form submit. When I print userid in the **Widget build(BuildContext context)**, it gives blank value.

Comment: I don't really know the solution but im very curious about this and what the issue is.

Comment: Please see my full code above. I got value of userid within initState() but not in the **Widget build(BuildContext context)** block. I got blank value. I initilized **TextEditingController uid;** above the initState() block also, but this also does not help!!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your TextController and userid variables first outside your initState in your state Class

```
    TextEditingController uid; 
    String userid;

         @override
         void initState() {
         super.initState();
          widget.storage.readCounter().then((int value) {
             userid = value.toString();
             uid = TextEditingController(text: userid);
           });
           print(userid); // This is to make sure you're actually getting a value back. Check your console.
         }
```

You should now have access to the value of "userid" through your TextEditingController

Comment: Sorry! This did not help. I printed and saw the value is printing inside the **initState()** block. I have to use the uid out of the initState() block in the **Widget build(BuildContext context)** block in a Form and get the value in form submit. But when I print the value in **Widget build(BuildContext context)** it gives blank value.

Comment: Can you send me more snippet of your code from your state Class to your build context.

Comment: This is my initState:                                                                                                                            **TextEditingController uid;
  static String userid;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.storage.readCounter().then((int value) {
      userid = value.toString();
      
    });
    uid = TextEditingController(text: userid);
  }**

Comment: And I am trying to get the value of uid in the **Widget build(BuildContext context)** block using **uid.text.**. I am getting the blank value.

Comment: I've made some adjustments to the solution code. Make sure you first initialize your variables (i.e. the TextEditingController and the userid) outside you initState.

Comment: I have already done this. I have initialized TextEditingController and the userid outside of initState().

Comment: The variable "userid" should now contain the value you need. Try printing the userid in the BuildContext.

Comment: Please see my full code. I have already kept **TextEditingController uid;** and  **static String userid;** above the initState() block. I got the value of userid in initState() but not getting the value out side of the block. When I print the value in Dialogbox I get the value but not getting the value in **Widget build(BuildContext context)** block which is out side of the initState() block. Am I clear now?

Comment: Please dont' give minus feedback. I have to increase my reputation. I had 15, after the feedback, it's 13 now. So please!

Comment: I'm not sure why the code is not working. I'm using a similar approach in my current project without any issues. Take another close look at your code, maybe you could be missing something. Don't worry about your reputation, getting a solution is more important. Hopefully, someone gives you a solution that works.

Comment: Ok. But did you understand my problem now? The **Widget build(BuildContext context)** is after the initState() block and I am not getting the value of uid in the Widget block, but getting in the initState() block.